# What did the Merovingian expect to happen when he told his goons to kill Neo?

Tags: the-matrix

The Merovingian is an old program. He knows the Matrix is in a cycle and why (he was an important part of the "nightmare" version of the Matrix). He's "survived" Neo's predecessors (previous Ones), so it stands to reason he's met at least one of them. He knows that Neo needs the Keymaker and claims to know the real reason why (so he can meet the Architect to restart the cycle). And he has underworld connections that make it very likely he knows of Neo's abilities, or at least that he's destroyed an Agent. (Heck, he probably already knows Smith is a virus.)

So when Neo confronts him in the mansion lobby, why does he send his goons at Neo with a flat "Kill him." and appear to be upset that they fail? Sure he feels disrespected by Neo's attitude but does he really expect the One to fall to a bunch of outlaws with minor (if any) supernatural abilities? And if they did succeed, wouldn't it ruin the cycle that he must be aware is necessary?

Comment: The “goons” lasted a lot longer than the *upgraded* agents did at the beginning of film (though there were more of them). I always figured they were very sophisticated programs.

Comment: No, Mr. Bond. He expected him to die.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> So when Neo confronts him in the mansion lobby, why does he send his goons at Neo with a flat "Kill him." and appear to be upset that they fail?

The Merovingian ordered his henchmen to attack Neo primarily as a stalling tactic to prevent Neo from protecting the Keymaker. The Merovingian had just ordered the Twins to recover the Keymaker, and the Twins would more likely succeed if they didn't have to contend with the One. Recovery of the Keymaker was so important that the loss of a bunch of henchmen was worth it to the Merovingian. The Merovingian would of course be upset at the loss of these henchmen even if he didn't expect them to win.

> Sure he feels disrespected by Neo's attitude but does he really expect the One to fall to a bunch of outlaws with minor (if any) supernatural abilities?

From the Merovingian's point of view it was *possible* for his henchmen to win -- Neo was continually growing in power and it would be difficult for the Merovingian to determine the threshold at which Neo became too powerful for his henchmen. While the Merovingian knew Neo was powerful, he didn't know just how powerful. On the one hand, he reacted with surprise ("okay, you have some skill") when Neo blocked all of the bullets fired by the Merovingian's henchmen. On the other hand, the Merovingian also commented that Neo's "predecessors had much more respect" (perhaps indicating that the previous Ones were less powerful when the Merovingian encountered them) and was encouraged that Neo could be beaten when Neo's hand *bled* after blocking a sword (remarking to his henchmen that "you see, he's just a man"<sup>1</sup>).

> And if they did succeed, wouldn't it ruin the cycle that he must be aware is necessary?

It's hard to say exactly what would happen if the One died before he reached the Architect and made his choice. But there are at least a couple of reasons why the Merovingian wouldn't view the completion of the cycle as *necessary* and/or why he would nonetheless want the One to fail:

1. The One and the Matrix cycles were an innovation of the Oracle, whom the Merovingian *hates*. If the One fails then it's also a failure of the Oracle and her system. That failure could lead to the Oracle's downfall, which the Merovingian might be able to take advantage of.
2. Even if the Matrix crashes the Merovingian would probably survive since he controls the Trainman, who in turn controls the [Mobil Avenue](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Mobil_Avenue) link between the Matrix and the machine world. Again, the failure of the Oracle's system of Matrix cycles is something the Merovingian can take advantage of -- it's not like he's particularly safe as an [exile](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Exile) that the existing system is trying to delete.
3. We're not exactly sure how the One is chosen, but the machines evidently have some control over it because [the machines *designed* the One to have a profound attachment to the rest of humanity](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/66706/31936). Neo is also told by the Architect that

   > The function of the One is now to return to the Source, allowing a temporary dissemination of the code you carry, reinserting the prime program.
   >
   > <sub>***The Matrix Reloaded* ([transcript](https://www.matrixfans.net/movies/the-matrix-reloaded/transcript/))**</sub>

   Presumably the machines insert the code carried by the One. **If the machines can control which human is the One, they can simply choose another human to complete the cycle if a One dies prematurely.**

---

<sup>1</sup>Credit goes to [@Jon Clements](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/16848/jon-clements) for reminding me of the sword block and the Merovingian's reaction to it.